# To refresh a project in intellij idea through java code

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to add some files dynamically to my project. I want to load those files as soon as they are added to my project. I am trying with the following code but it is not working :

```
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
     e.getProject().getProjectFile().refresh(true, true);

  }
```

Comment: load to where? project view?

Comment: yes...I also tried with this code... still not working ,...    RefreshQueue.getInstance().refresh(true,true,null,e.getProject().getProjectFile());

Comment: what about this ProjectView#refresh?

Comment: @Meo still not working.... :( ProjectView.getInstance(e.getProject()).refresh();

Comment: Is this for a plugin?

Comment: @Engineer Dollery : yes...that is for a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto refresh works with this code :

```
    VirtualFileManager.getInstance().syncRefresh();
```